# Шахматка из sql запроса в FirebirdDB

Tags: sql, firebird

Делаю такой запрос .

```
select fio, nopr, Count(*)
   from patient INNER JOIN oprs ON patient.uid = oprs.uid
   INNER JOIN n_otd ON oprs.otd = n_otd.otd
   INNER JOIN n_opr ON oprs.opr = n_opr.opr
   INNER JOIN N_MPS ON oprs.doc = n_mps.kmp
   INNER JOIN NP_ANS ON oprs.ans = np_ans.ans
   INNER JOIN N_OPL ON oprs.opl = n_opl.opl
WHERE n_otd.notd = 'Хирургическое отделение'
AND (oprs.dvo between "01.02.2016" AND "15.02.2016") GROUP BY fio, nopr
```

Получаю такой вывод:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как построить запрос, чтобы выводилась шахматка и вообще реально ли это?

Результат должен выглядеть как то так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поясните подробнее, что нужно получить и в каком виде

Comment: добавил в описание темы

Comment: Pivot/Unpivot? Посмотрите тут - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29896351/pivot-rows-into-columns-firebird-2-5

Comment: это прям совсем не тот случай, в том решение название полей известны., в моем случае нет.

Comment: Вам это необходимо сделать одним запросом? Или же сделать запрос для дальнейшего отображения в отчете/гриде?

Comment: Желательно одним запросом сделать, потом отправлю ответ в виде json в фроненд, там уже буду таблицу рисовать.

Answer (score 1):

Могу предложить 2 варианта.

1. Делается запрос, возвращающий список столбцов (наименования по-русски и уникальный код для отсева данных именно по этому столбцу. Возможно, еще наименования латиницей). На основании этих данных динамически строится основной запрос.
2. Сделать все на клиенте. Это значительно проще.

Comment: Ко второму варианту я тоже больше склоняюсь, но хотелось бы увидеть пример реализации первый